# Find all positive integer solutions of the inequality $\sigma(n)-\varphi(n) \le 4\sqrt{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integer solutions to the equation:
$$\sigma(n)-\varphi(n) \le 4\sqrt{n}$$
$\sigma (n)$ is the function that sums all the divisor of $n$ and $\varphi(n)$ is the Euler totient function.

I couldn’t figure out the problem, could someone help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: primes work....

Comment: $n=p^2$ also work

Comment: $\sigma(n) - \varphi(n) > n - (1 - \frac{1}{p})n = \frac{n}{p}$ where $p$ is prime divisor of $n$. If $n$ has $\ge 3$ prime divisors, we can choose $p \le \sqrt[3]{n}$. So $\sigma(n) - \varphi(n) > n^{\frac{2}{3}} > 4\sqrt{n}$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: $n$ is not of the form $pq$ where $p,q$ are different primes: $\sigma(pq)-\varphi(pq) = (1+p+q+pq)-(1-p-q+pq) > 4\sqrt{pq}$. And for every $n<4096$ with $\ge 3$ prime divisors, $\sigma(n)-\varphi(n) > 4\sqrt{n}$. Thus $\sigma(n)-\varphi(n) \le 4\sqrt{n}$ only if $n=1$, $p$ or $p^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I find the following positive integer solutions.

**I.** Since for prime $n$, $\sigma(n)=n+1$, and $\phi(n)=n-1$, then for prime $n\ge 1$,$$\sigma(n)-\phi(n)=2\le 4\sqrt n$$

**II.** Since for odd prime $n^2$, $\sigma(n^2)=n^2+n+1$, and $\phi(n^2)=n^2-n$, then for $n\ge 1$,$$\sigma(n^2)-\phi(n^2)=2n+1\le 4n=4\sqrt{n^2}$$

**III.** Since for $n=2^m$, $\sigma(n)=2^{m+1}-1$, and $\phi(n)=2^{m-1}$, then$$\sigma(n)-\phi(n)=2^{m+1}-1-2^{m-1}=3\cdot2^{m-1}$$And since$$\sqrt n=2^\frac{m}{2}$$so that$$4\sqrt n=2^\frac{4+m}{2}$$we find$$3\cdot2^{m-1}>2^\frac{4+m}{2}$$for $m>3$.

Thus for $n=2^m$, $\sigma(n)-\phi(n)\le4\sqrt n$ only if $n\le8$.